# MATLAB: Resize a vector using a Conditional

Tags: matlab, vector

I have three vectors: state, position, and index. Each has 50 elements. I am trying to produce a graph for position vs. index, but only if the values of state are from 2 to 5. For example, for the data:

0 13 3

2 24 1

1 18 2

5 71 0

I would like the code to only graph the points for the second and fourth lines (since the state is between 2 and 5) for values 24,1 and 71,0.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not so bad.  First create a `logical` vector where we search for states that are between 2 and 5.  After that, subset your `position` and `index` vectors using this `logical` vector to extract this information.  Assuming that your vectors are called `state`, `position` and `index`, you would do this:

```
loc = state >= 2 & state <= 5;
stateFinal = state(loc);
positionFinal = position(loc);
indexFinal = index(loc);

figure;
plot(indexFinal, positionFinal, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 14);
xlabel('Index');
ylabel('Position');
```

Here, `index` is on the x-axis while `position` is on the y-axis, as per the requirements of your post.  I have also opted to plot each point using single dots and in blue, hence the `'b.'` parameter for the third variable of `plot`.  I have also increased the size of each point to 14 to make the dots clearly visible.  The default behaviour for `plot` is to connect all of the points together using straight lines.  Because I don't know the nature of your data, I have opted to plot single points instead.

---

As an additional bonus, here is code that will plot `position` vs. `index` and I colour code the points based on which state each point belongs to.  In other words:

```
colours = 'rgbk';
figure;
hold on;
for idx = 2 : 5
    stt = stateFinal == idx;
    pos = positionFinal(stt);
    ind = indexFinal(stt);
    plot(ind, pos, [colours(idx-1) '.'], 'MarkerSize', 14);
end
xlabel('Index');
ylabel('Position');
legend('State 2', 'State 3', 'State 4', 'State 5');
```

Here state #2 is colour coded in red, #3 in green, #4 in blue and #5 in black.  I've also thrown in a legend in case you get confused.

---

If this is not what you intended, please let me know by leaving me a comment on this post.  However, the logic to subset your data based on whether or not the index is between 2 and 5 is the most important point that is addressed in your question, and those are the first four lines of the code shown above.

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Want to help me change the dots to small lines of a specified length? I don't want the lines to connect...

Comment: @user3788687 - You're very welcome.  Sure! I'd love to help.  What do you mean by "small lines"? Do you mean something like dashed lines in between each point?.  Something like: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/line_script3.png ? Look at the red line.

Comment: @user3788687 - I've modified my post to give you some more bonus code.  I also misread your post.  You want to plot position on the y axis while index is on the x axis.  Let me know about the "small lines" bit.